# For Loop Exceeding range for pandas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib, plot

I am writing a script that takes a pandas data frame for two separate items and plots timeseries data for each.

So i have a dateframe df that looks something like this

```
                     V: a-1  V: a-2  V: a-3  V: b-1  V: b-2  V: b-3
TimeDT:                                     
2018-02-11 22:00:00    1       3        5        7      4        3
2018-02-11 22:05:00    2       3        6        5      5        4
...
```

When I write it as a function,

```
def generate_voltage_plot(file_path, length, arg1, arg2):
    plt.figure()
    for i in range(length):
        plt.plot( arg1, '-', color=myColors['cool'][i])
    for i in range(length):
        plt.plot( arg2, '-', color=myColors['warm'][i])
    plt.title('V [V]')
    plt.ylabel('V [V]')
    plt.savefig(file_path)

generate_voltage_plot('Vplot.png', 3, df['V: a-' + str(i + 1)], df['V: b-' + str(i + 1)]
```

i get this error.

```
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'V: a-6'
```

I do not understand why it is looping past 3. It does not happen when I run it not as a function. Thank you for any guidance, or a better way to do this.

Comment: what is i equal to before you call generate_voltage_plot?  how are you defining it?

Comment: **i** is not a global variable. You cannot pass it in the arguments.

Comment: From the dataframe you showed above, there is no column called "V: a-6" in your data.

Comment: @MohammadAthar I have tried leaving it undefined and setting it to zero.

Comment: you need to post a mcve: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so we can better understand what you're doing

Comment: @YilunZhang That is correct, my for loop should only loop to a-3, but it keeps going to a-6 for whatever reason.

Comment: @Jared I don't see the logic of `i` in your code when calling that function. That's probably where the problem is.

Comment: @YilunZhang reorganizing my function so that i was no longer needed in my argument fixed it.